# Elasticsearch query by date returning incorrect results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, couchbase

So, I have a series of documents that are stored as pure Json in a NoSQL database (Couchbase). These documents include a "Created" field which contains a DateTime value. I'm performing the following query through Elasticsearch and it is returning results that I would not expect it to return.

Query:

```
"query":
{ 
"bool": 
{
    "must": [
    {
        "range": 
        {
            "couchbaseDocument.doc.Created": 
            { 
                "from":"2014-03-27T00:00:00.0000000",
                "to": "2014-03-27T23:59:00.0000000"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "term":
        {
            "couchbaseDocument.meta.expiration": "0"
        }
    }],
    "must_not": [ ],
    "should": [ ]
}, 
from: 0, 
size:25000  
}
```

I would expect this query to only return results with a Created date some time during 3/27. However, I'm getting some results from 3/26. For instance, it is returning one document with the following created field:

```
"Created": "2014-03-26T21:40:26.2856631-04:00"
```

Why is this document being returned in the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is searching for date/times in the GMT timezone (aka UTC; aka Zulu time), which is to say that there is an implicit `+00:00` at the end of them.

```
"from" : "2014-03-27T00:00:00.0000000+00:00",
"to"   : "2014-03-27T23:59:00.0000000+00:00"
```

GMT is a pretty standard timezone for storing date/times, but it appears that you have documents that are stored in a different timezone (they appear to be either a late EDT or AST, which is the [Atlantic Time Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_Time_Zone)), which is `-04:00` or 4 hours behind GMT. Therefore, when it it is `midnight on March 27, 2014 in GMT`, it is still `8 PM on March 26, 2014 in AST` (8 PM is the 20th hour of the day).

In essence, when you see `-04:00`, then you need to *add* `04:00` to the time, which is 4 hours and 0 minutes. Once done, then you can drop the timezone marker because:

```
2014-03-26T21:40:26.2856631-04:00
```

is the same as

```
2014-03-27T01:40:26.2856631+00:00
```

which is the same as

```
2014-03-27T01:40:26.2856631
```

because `21 + 04 = 25`, and hour `25` of a day is hour `01` of the *next* day (`25 - 24 = 01`, thus giving 1 day and 1 hour; it is noteworthy that `24 - 24 = 00`, which is why `00` represents midnight).

To bring it all back to the question: the time returned *should* be in your results because with respect to GMT, it is within bounds of your search.

For reference, EST is `-05:00` and PST is `-08:00`.

Comment: Yep, looks like I was storing my documents as local time instead of UTC. Thanks!